# Read output output of a script with spark streaming

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a script similar to this one

```py
import json 
def line_generator():
    d = dict({1:1, 2:2, 3:3})
    while True:
        yield json.dumps(d)

it = line_generator()
for l in it:
    print(l)
```

which output values to stdout. I would like to "catch" those values with the spark Streaming api to store them in parquet files, and apply some inference code which is written is HiveQL. I am not a Scala person :/ so, if possible, I would prefer to have a solution in PySpark but am happy with any piece of advice.

I know it is possible to read stream of data coming from a Kafka stream for example, is there a similar way to read data sent to stdout or data that are continuously writtten to a file ?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Is spark really necessary, what if you could convert to parquet without using spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't work with stdout as spark is usually used on a cluster with several nodes. A better way would be kafka (which also allows you to store the data temporarily and is more reliable) or sockets. Below a socket example (on the basis of [Daniel Hynk](http://danielhnyk.cz/simple-server-client-aplication-python-3/)):

```py
#send your data
import socket
import json          

def line_generator():
    d = dict({1:1, 2:2, 3:3}) 
    while True:
        yield json.dumps(d)

hostip = '127.0.0.1'
portno = 56789 

#listener need to be started before!
#try: netcat -lkp 56789
#before you start with spark streaming

soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
soc.connect((hostip, portno))

it = line_generator()
for l in it:
    soc.send(l.encode('utf8'))
```

Spark structured streaming example:

```py
hostip = '127.0.0.1'
portno = '56789'

received = spark.readStream.format("socket").option("host", hostip).option("port", portno).load()

#the value column of a structured stream contains the content
values = received.select(received.value)

###
#do your stuff
###

#will listen to the specified port and write the results to memory!!! until you call query.stop()
#this allows you to see the data with select * from mystream
query = values.writeStream.queryName("mystream").outputMode("complete").format("memory").start()
```

Of course you don't want to write it to memory in the end but it speeds up the development a lot. After you have finished your program just change the last line to something like below as mentioned in the [guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html):

```py
writeStream.format("parquet").option("path", "path/to/destination/dir").start()
```

Comment: Please keep in mind, `socket` streaming source is not meant for production usage. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#creating-streaming-dataframes-and-streaming-datasets